# Webpack build module with non ascii characters

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, plotly

I'm trying to get Webpack 2.0 to build the un-minified version of plotly.js in a ReactJS application. The issue is that plotly.js contains some non-ascii characters, and Webpack gets the error "Module build failed: [...] Unexpected character [non-ascii charater]". Any ideas on how to get Webpack to not error about these characters?

Alternatively, if I could get Webpack to not warn about the pre-minified plotly.min.js file that could also work, but I would rather have Webpack build it.

Comment: How exactly did you install plotly.js? I think the non-ascii character may be a red herring.

Comment: I'm working in an offline environment and using the yarn package manager, but plotly won't install using the offline feature, so I added a copy of the un-minified plotly.js file to my project files, and then I'm importing it using es6 style imports. 

The github documentation lists that they use non-ascii characters to represent some graphing variables.

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js#webpack-usage-with-modules